# How to identify all tags used in website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

The BeautifulSoup equivalent I am trying to accomplish is:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html)
tags = {tag.name for tag in page_soup.find_all()}
tags
```

How do I do this using Selenium? I'm just trying to print out the unique tags used by a website without having to go through the entire HTML source code, so I can begin analysing it and scrape specific parts of the website. I don't care what the content of the tags are at this point, I just want to know what tags are used.

An answer I've stumbled upon, but not sure if there is a more elegant way of doing things is this...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

website = 'https://www.afr.com'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(website)

el = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='*')

tag_list = []

for e in el:
    tag_list.append(e.tag_name)

tag_list = pd.Series(tag_list).unique()

for t in tag_list:
    print(t)
```

Comment: I can help you with all the tags using xpath 1.0, however if you are looking for specifically unique tags I will pass it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautifulsoup is better for this specific scenario.

But if you still want to use Selenium, you can try:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('*')

tags = []
for x in elems:
    taggs.append(x.tag_name)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('*')

tags = [x.tag_name for x in elems]
```

If you finally want to get only the unique values, you could use the `set()` built-in data type for example:

```
set(tags)
```

Comment: I found BeautifulSoup easier, but I'm trying to work my way up to scraping some websites that don't play well with BS. Selenium may or may not be the answer at this stage.